# What do you make of the quoted paragraph below?

Tags: indefinite-articles, parallelism, possessive-determiners

I pulled this paragraph from an English textbook written for beginner's level (A1 according to CEFR) English learners in my country (Vietnam). The question I want to ask is: Can you understand what the paragraph is trying to say?

> People are living longer so there are more elderly people. Many young people are doing community service. They help elderly people. They do their shopping. They do their housework. They clean their yards. They even paint their houses.

A friend of mine, an English teacher, suggested that the multiple instances of *their* in the paragraph may be source for confusion and proposed changing *their* to *the*, i.e.:

> People are living longer so there are more elderly people. Many young people are doing community service. They help elderly people. They do *the* shopping. They do *the* housework. They clean *the* yards. They even paint *the* houses.

How about you? How would you fix this paragraph, or should it need fixing?

Comment: The paragraph is clear as-is, as all antecedents can be inferred from context.  Your friend's suggestion muddies that by removing the information that it's the elderly people's houses.

Comment: There are a lot of *they* and *their*, but the parallel structure of the sentences should make it easy to deduce that *they* is "young people" and *their* is "elderly people's".

Comment: I agree with Ryan and Hellion. *their* is used consistently to refer back to the old people. Changing it to *the* removes that reference and introduces confusing ambiguity.

Comment: There is a strong sense of parallelism,; one has to be in a logic class to posit that the _their_'s don't have 'elderley people' as their common antecedent. And ELU looks at standard usage, not logical quibbles. Pragmatics is vital.

Answer (score 1):

Common sense tells us what the paragraph is trying to say, but it does read oddly because *logically* it could be telling us that the young people do their own shopping etc. I don't think that substituting *the* for *their* is any improvement.

I would suggest *They help elderly people with shopping, housework, cleaning yards and even house-painting.*